# AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'fullname' as well as in apply_raise()

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

```
class Employee:
    raise_amt = 1.04
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):

          self.first = first
          self.last  = last
          self.email = first + '.'+ last + '@company.com'
          self.pay   = pay


          def fullname(self):

            return '{} {}'. format(self.first, self.last)

          def apply_raise(self):

            self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)    

dev_1 = Employee('nikhil', 'bante', 50000)
dev_2 = Employee('vipin', 'raut', 60000)          


print(dev_1.fullname())
print(dev_1.email)

print(dev_2.email)    
dev_1.apply_raise()
print(dev_1.pay)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fullname function is indented too much. It should be at the same level as the `__init__` function.

The way you have it right now, instead of the functions belonging to the class, the `fullname` and `apply_raise` functions are sub-functions of the `__init__` function. Unindenting the functions so that they are only one indentation level more than the class will make the functions belong to the class instead.